# Разбор синтаксиса псевдоязыка с помощью регулярных выражений

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Пытаюсь реализовать парсер кода `PL/SQL` подобного языка, чтобы сделать подсветку кода на HTML.

Прошу помощи, т.к. просто встал на непонимании как делать замену найденной матчером группы при мультисовпадении.

пример:

```
    StringBuffer sourceString = new StringBuffer("::[PROPERTY_PROD].[LIB].DelProperty(this, ::[KIND_PROP_PROD]([CODE] = 'TUNE_WORK_DATE')); --комментарий кода");
    StringBuffer pattLine = new StringBuffer();

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(::)|(\\[)|(\\.)|(')|(])");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(sourceString);

    StringBuffer parsedLine = new StringBuffer();
    while (m.find()){
        //как тут корректно сделать замену, сдвигая позицию для следующего поиска?
        sourceString.replace(m.start(),m.end(),"<c>"+m.group()+"</c>");
    }

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(sourceString+"");
```

Понятно, что матчер ищет данные рекурсивно, и такой вариант не подходит по этой причине, но я думаю, что должна быть какая-то возможность сделать это безопасно.
Я так же пробовал сделать рекурсивную функцию, но тот вариант более не оптимальный, т.к. на каждое стек множится на количество совпадений.

Вероятно, я выбрал для этой задачи неверный подход, и буду очень признателен за наводку.

Comment: твоя цель -- парсер, или подсветка?  Если последнее, посмотри тут:  https://codemirror.net/ . Библиотека выглядит очень простой и поддерживает SQL.

Comment: цель сделать подсветку. для этого парсить не нужно? codemirror.net - это библиотека на JSе. ПО сути мне надо в нее передать уже заврапленный код.

Comment: Зачем изобретать велосипед (если только тебе не нужен особо уникальный)? Да, думаю, достаточно просто передать туда код